# Query para ordenar Insercion de datos

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

Saludos. Al clickear al boton + en la segunda fila de la tabla 1 obtengo el resultado de la tabla 2(nueva fila). Necesito que cuando actualice la pagina, los datos se mantengan en la posicion donde se crearon o eliminaron. Que tipo de query necesitaria?

[image: Imagen]

Adjunto La Bdd hasta ahora, como podran observar, es sencilla

[image: bdd]

**SOLUCION**

Este es el query que ordena la tabla. Gracias por sus aportes. Se debe crear una columna sub_id que inserte el id de la fila clickeada y para mayor ordenamiento crear una columna para almacenar la fecha de insercion

```
SELECT * FROM test ORDER BY sub_id,fecha
```

Comment: es no es definitivamente un problema de la base de datos, ni que puedas resolver con PHP, porque todo esto deberia hacerse del lado del usuario (no del servidor). y vas a tener que guardar el orden de las filas en la bd y modificarlo cada vez que cambie algo.. por eso estas cosas no se hacen en bases de datos, si no en archivos formateados..

Comment: hola @gbianchi las acciones del lado del usuario ya estan listas, yo puedo crear y eliminar las filas, pero necesito el query que me renderize la tabla tal cual yo la "envie" hacia el servidor.

Comment: entonces explica eso en la pregunta. No queda claro donde esta el problema si no cuentas todo eso.. como guardas la info en la base de datos? como la recuperas?

Comment: eso es lo que pregunte, el problema esta en el query, necesito uno que me renderize la tabla tal cual como en la vista se modifico

Comment: y tu modelo de base de datos? falta esa informacion..

Comment: eso si falto, ya la anexo, gracias por la acotacion

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69453/discussion-between-osmelg-and-gbianchi).

Comment: @osmelg no edites la publicación para poner la solución en la propia pregunta, en su lugar crea una respuesta con la solución. Por favor lee [ask] y [answer] y mueve la solución a una respuesta.

Comment: hola @AlvaroMontoro la publicacion esta cerrada, por tanto no puedo crear una respuesta